# How to Select data from python with odoo have condition by groupby parent_id

Tags: python, odoo-9

```
class address(models.Model):
    _name = 'address.add'

    name = fields.Char(string='ឈ្មោះ')
    parent_id = fields.Many2one('address.add')
    child_id = fields.One2many('address.add', 'parent_id')
    parent_left = fields.Integer('Left Parent', select=1)
    parent_right = fields.Integer('Right Parent', select=1)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and what kind of error you have faced so far..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```py
  # domain: a valid domain
  # fields: list if field ex: ['name', 'partner_id']
  self.env['address.add'].read_group(domain, fields, groupy=['partner_id'])
```

you can read the documentation in `models.py`